# "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using UniqueDeviceID

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, deviceid

I am developing a project on ionic v3.
I want to get a unique device id in my application.
I followed the instructions at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/

**ts file:**

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';   

constructor(private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) { }

login(){
  this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
   .then((uuid: any) => console.log(uuid))
   .catch((error: any) => console.log(error)); 
}
```

**In app.module.ts :**

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    UniqueDeviceID,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AuthServiceProvider
  ]
```

When I am running it error occur:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sujagSindhiSamiti",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the package.json also in the question?

Comment: package.json is added in question @Vinaysharma

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-in-error-error-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-at-uniquedeviceid-get/155093

Comment: You are running this in an emulator/real device right? Native functionalities won't work in a browser.

Comment: I follow instruction from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device for browser also but still same error @Vinaysharma

Comment: I tried to run it on the device. it is not working. @Vinaysharma

Comment: Let's chat in this chatroom @UnnatiPatadia - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205733/imei-number-cordova-plugin

Comment: Thank you @UnnatiPatadia It's working like charm for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you’re using Ionic v3.9.9 so you can’t use Ionic Native 5, because it requires Ionic v4.

Update the @ionic-native/* dependencies in your package.json to "4.20.0" and run npm install. That should fix all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Follow v3 [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/unique-device-id/).

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/unique-device-id@4
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ionic Device Plugin for getting UUID.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device

This plugin also provides following facilities.

model,
platform,
uuid,
version,
manufacturer,
serial,
isVirtual